Port Scanner not SCANNING
I am new to the world of scripting. I was learning about the python and scripting.
Build a Port Scanner, through 'The Cyber Mentor' Course. Using Oracle VM for this.
I do not know whether the speed is slow or there is any problem.
Created if-else loop and it works OK.Image.
The main problem is that I have created a try-except to check whether any port that ranges from 50-80 is open in the given IP address. But it does not print anything, not even the "Checking port" line.Image
The result I get everytime; It keeps on loading.Result

Welcome to StackOverflow! It is a lot easier for others to read and test your code if you paste it instead of using screenshots (start a line with ```python, then paste your code below, then end it with ``` below the last line of code)

https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

socket.setdefaulttimeout() sets the timeout for new socket objects (documentation). (You probably meant to use s.settimeout(1) here.) The solution is to move socket.setdefaulttimeout(1) to be above your try block.
